# Merging two arrays and their data

Tags: php, arrays, facebook, object

I have an issue I can't figure out how to solve: I load some facebook posts on a website using their api. The posts can have videos, so I want to load those videos in an iframe, ofcourse the correct video must be loaded with the post it belongs to.

Easier said than done, because that information is stored inside two objects, the `posts` object contains stuff like the post message etcetera while the `videos` object contains all videos from a page.

I want to use information from both objects inside one loop, so my idea was to combine both objects/arrays like so:

```
<?php
$json_object = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/pageid/posts?fields=full_picture,message,picture,story,permalink_url,updated_time,from&access_token=myaccesstoken");

$feedarray = json_decode($json_object);

$json_objectvideo = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/pageid/videos?fields=embed_html,permalink_url&access_token=myaccesstoken");

$feedvideo = json_decode($json_objectvideo);

$merged = array_merge($feedarray->data, $feedvideo->data);
?>
```

When I print $merged, it shows one big array with first all posts and then all videos (as expected). How can I make sure, that when I loop this array, the correct `embed_html` field is loaded with the correct post? I noticed they are connected somehow with their ids. A post id looks like this for example:

```
367712570004555_1287302444712225
```

While a video id looks like:

```
1287302444712225
```

So I need to explode the post id on the underscore, if I then take the last part, both ids are the same. Knowing that info, how can I use it to load the correct embed_html with the correct post inside a loop?

To clarify here is part of the `posts` object (when not merged ofcourse):

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2017-09-12T20:58:21+0000",
         "message": "Vandaag bij Vivienne Westwood Boutique Amsterdam de lichtreclame gemonteerd. Mooi project om te mogen doen.\n\u2705  maatwerk\n\u2705  kwaliteit\n\u2705  betaalbaar\n\ud83d\udc4b  Benieuwd naar de kosten? We helpen je graag!\n- Reclame & Internet - #ontwerp > #productie > #montage",
         "id": "367712570004555_1287302444712225"
      },
```

And the `videos` object:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "embed_html": "\u003Ciframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.facebook.com\u00252Fwebsite\u00252Fvideos\u00252F1287302444712225\u00252F&width=1280\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\"true\" allowFullScreen=\"true\">\u003C/iframe>",
         "permalink_url": "/website/videos/1287302444712225/",
         "id": "1287302444712225"
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and hope you're trying to do the same as per your question merging posts and videos as per there ids.

```
<?php

$posts = '{
   "data": [
      {
         "created_time": "2017-09-12T20:58:21+0000",
         "message": "Vandaag bij Vivienne Westwood Boutique Amsterdam de lichtreclame gemonteerd. Mooi project om te mogen doen.\n\u2705  maatwerk\n\u2705  kwaliteit\n\u2705  betaalbaar\n\ud83d\udc4b  Benieuwd naar de kosten? We helpen je graag!\n- Reclame & Internet - #ontwerp > #productie > #montage",
         "id": "367712570004555_1287302444712225"
      }
      ]
   }';
$videos = '{
       "data": [
       {
         "embed_html": "\u003Ciframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.facebook.com\u00252Fwebsite\u00252Fvideos\u00252F1287302444712225\u00252F&width=1280\" width=\"1280\" height=\"720\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\"true\" allowFullScreen=\"true\">\u003C/iframe>",
         "permalink_url": "/website/videos/1287302444712225/",
         "id": "1287302444712225"
      }
    ]
}';

$x = json_decode($posts, true)['data'];
$y = json_decode($videos, true)['data'];

foreach($x as $key => $value) {
    $id = explode('_', $value['id'])[1];
    foreach($y as $key => $vide){
        if($vide['id'] == $id) {
            $combinedArr[] = array_merge($vide, $value);
        }
    }   
}
print_r($combinedArr);

?>
```

Hope this helps !